# Is this sorting possible in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting

I am now having a problem sorting the data in my PHP page where the data displayed is combined of two tables as the both tables are linked by a foreign key in one of the table.

two tables are as below

***Table name: Students*** 

stu_id 
stu_name 
.
.
.
stu_course_id

***Table name: courses*

course_id

course_name**

Wen displaying the data it is displayed in following format:

**Student id | Student name | student course 

----1 --------------john-------------engineering 

----2--------------dave---------------business**

I am able to sort the data by name which is pretty easy but I am having difficulty sorting the data by course name. Is this possible as the course name is not in the same table as student?

Comment: should be fine, what is your actual SQL string?

Comment: of course it's possible, if you joined the tables before and then use the usual ORDER BY...

Comment: Any followup on this question? Is it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select s.stu_id, s.stu_name, c.course_name
from students s
inner join courses c on s.stu_course_id = c.course_id
order by c.course_name asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT * FROM courses ORDER BY course_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Simply refer to the column name without ambiguity, i.e.:

`ORDER BY courses.course_name`

Show me your query and I'll make that work.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I will make it work now, didn't know that you can join the tables in MYSQL. I will lear how join work and will implement the solutions you have provided. Thanks once again.